# How to install 15.04 in not UEFI mode

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, 15.04

I've got Windows 8.1 installed in not UEFI mode. 
I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.04, the problem is that my usb stick wouldn't boot. 
The only way I got it to boot my USB stick was turning my BIOS to UEFI mode but when I was installing there was a warning message saying that one of my installed OS (W8.1) was in a not UEFI mode and that could bring me problems later.

So my question is, if I want to install Ubuntu 15.04 alongside a nonUEFI system, is there a different procedure than the normal one I've read here?
How can I make my system to boot my USB stick in NON UEFI mode?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if your system is UEFI based you will need to enable legacy mode in the BIOS and boot from the CD drive or USB using the legacy interface. In my BIOS options for example, it lists CD drive as UEFI CD Drive and just CD drive. You would need to choose the regular CD drive to boot via legacy mode.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I've been looking for a similar option in my BIOS option but I haven't find any. The only way that I can boot my USB stick is in UEFI mode, not in CSM. Do you know if this has to do with the program I used to burn my USB stick or anything like this?

Comment: Should be maybe something like enable legacy USB boot, or legacy devices, as well.

Comment: Ah yes, this is eneble but yet when booting from USB (in CSM mode) the screen stays black with a blincking white dash and nothing happens..

Comment: Yes, some programs for creating a bootable USB drive omit one boot loader or another. Check your program for options, or try another program. Some people have better luck with optical media than with USB drives, but of course many new computers lack optical drives.

Comment: **@SantiagoFerrariGonzález**:  As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: **woahguy**: please drop by the [Ask Ubuntu General chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) and send a message @Fabby